# Multiple choices from a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I have an arraylist with objects and a running Gui. I looking for a way to popup a little frame or box or something like that which displays the objects from the arraylist. The user now should be able to choose one or more items which are then returned.

I have already the optionpane but i can just select one object

```
    Object[] possibilities = lr.declarationList.toArray();
    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        gui.getFrame(),
                        "Choose Target Nodes",
                        "Customized Dialog",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        possibilities,
                        null);
```

maybe a popup list would help out.

Comment: Have you tried to run the corresponding example from the [How to Use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) in Java Tutorial? Place [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) here. By the way, have you tried to set possibilities to a simple array ({"ham", "spam", "yam"}).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using [`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a JList component argument whose elements are sourced from your list, for example:

```java
JList list = new JList(new String[] {"foo", "bar", "gah"});
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
  null, list, "Multi-Select Example", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.getSelectedIndices()));
```

Note that if you need more layout items in the message object itself you can pack them all into a JPanel and use that component as the message argument.

Comment: maybe JComboBox +1 :-) {"ham", "spam", "yam"} :-)

Comment: Thank you very kindly for your simple, clear answer! I've been banding around for two hours trying to figure out how to do this. I am horrified at how complicated I managed to make my first partially-working version...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using `JCheckBox`:

```
import javafx.util.Pair;

public static <T> List<T> select(Component parent, String message, List<T> variants) {
        List<Pair<JCheckBox, T>> boxes = variants
                .stream()
                .map(variant -> new Pair<>(new JCheckBox(String.valueOf(variant)), variant))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        boxes.forEach(p -> panel.add(p.getKey(),
                new GridBagConstraints(
                        0,
                        boxes.indexOf(p),
                        1,
                        1,
                        1.0,
                        1.0,
                        GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        0,
                        0
                )
        ));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, panel, message, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        return boxes.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getKey().isSelected())
                .map(Pair::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```